# Meaning of get another shot

Tags: meaning

What is the meaning of **get another shot** in the following sentence.

[Both now get another shot at correcting these anomalies, and the first step among many more to follow will be made on Thursday.](https://www.thehindu.com/opinion/editorial/a-cup-to-win/article27297832.ece)

I think in such cases **have a shot at something/give it a shot** type constructions are used.

Is the sentence given grammatical

Answer (score 1):

It is grammatical and idiomatic.

"Get another shot" means "Be allowed another attempt."

> Having failed to win the world cup in 2015, India will get another shot at it this year.